Typescript Type error: Type '{ params: PageParams; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'
this page is taking gutenberg blocks via api from wordpress and passing them to BlockRenderer component  /app/[...slug]/page.tsx:
import { BlockRenderer } from "../components/BlockRenderer";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { getPage } from "../../api/getPage";
import { Block } from "../../api/types"; // Adjust this import based on where your Block type is defined


interface PageProps {
  params: {
    slug: string[]; // Assuming slug is an array of strings
  };
  
}

export default async function Page({ params }: PageProps) {
  const { slug } = await params;

  const data: Block[] | null = await getPage(slug.join("/")); // Assuming getPage returns Block[] or null

  
  if (!data) {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <div>
           <BlockRenderer blocks={data || []} />;
    </div>

  )
  
 
}

"../../api/types":
export interface Block {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  attributes: BlockAttributes; // Attributes are optional
  innerBlocks?: InnerBlock[]; // Optional, as some blocks may not have inner blocks
  
}
export interface InnerBlock extends Block {
  innerBlocks?: InnerBlock[];  // Recursive definition for nested blocks
}
export interface BlockRendererProps {
  blocks: Block[]; // Array of Block objects
}
export interface BlockAttributes {
  id?: number,
  level?: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6; // Optional, used in heading blocks
  content: string; // Optional, used in paragraph and heading blocks
  isStackedOnMobile?: boolean; // Optional, used in columns block
  width: string;
  textAlign?: string;
  textColor: ThemeKeys;
  style?: StyleAttributes;
  [key: string]: any;
}

error:
Type error: Type '{ params: PageParams; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'.
  Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
    Type 'PageParams' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]

Whole thing works just fine on development mode .
I tried changing params types , but it doesnt helped.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that others can copy and paste into their own IDEs and see the issue you're seeing. Right now there are a bunch of references to private/third-party things that we don't have. Instead of just giving us an excerpt of your code, you should go through the process of making a self-contained [mre] as described within the link that appears every time I say [mre].  [mre].  Good luck!

Why are you using const { slug } = await params;? Accordingly with you pageProps it is a simple object that contains a slug property not a Promise.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you using NextJS 15? How is PageParams defined?

Since Nextjs 15 params is a promise. You are awaiting the promise correctly before using it but in the PageProps you're marking it as {slug: string[]}, so try using
interface PageProps {
  params: Promise<{
    slug: string[];
  }>;
}

Nextjs doc regarding this
